# Using "execv" or "execvp" to morph a program to isPrime?

Tags: c, executable

I have a program called 'prime.c' below:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <unistd.h>

int isPrime(int number);
void Morph(char *number);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int i;

        int number;

        if (argc < 2) {
            printf("Returning 2");
            return(2);
        }
        else number = atoi(argv[1]);
        if (isPrime(number)) {
                exit(1);
        }
        exit(0);
}


/*
Purpose: check if the input number is a prime number
input:
number - the number to be checked

return:
0 - if the number is not a prime number
1 - if the number is a prime number
*/
int isPrime(int number)
{
        int i;
        for(i = 2; i*i < number; i++) {
                usleep(100);
                if (number % i == 0) {
                        printf("%d is not a prime number!",number);
                        return(0);
                }
        }
        printf("%d is a prime number!",number);
        return(1);
}

void Morph(char *number)
{
        execvp(isPrime.exe,number);            
}
```

Which takes in a number and checks to see if it's a prime number or not. We were to create an executable called 'isPrime.exe' which I did using 'gcc -o isPrime.exe prime.c -lm' and everything worked perfectly. The next step is where I'm stuck, we are to create a function Morph(char *number) which takes in a string as the number and morphs the program to the isPrime program using either execv or execvp. I've started to create the morph function however I can't get it to work, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Starting by reading a [reference of the functions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) might be a good idea.

Comment: You are missing the double quotes around the file path.

Comment: I've read through them but I'm still having trouble

Comment: Not sure if it's the same problem but last time I used exec it didn't include the filename parameter so I had to change all my argv[1]s to argh[0]

Comment: if the input number is 4, then this algorithm 'isPrime()' fails to provide the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [the reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) you will see that e.g. the `execvp` function takes a string as first argument, and an `argv` style array as it second argument.

The first argument is the path (relative from the current process current working directory, or an absolute path) to the executable you want to run. The second argument is what will become the `argv` argument in the new program.

So lets say that your `isPrime.exe` is in the same directory as the current program, then you could call it like this:

```
char *primeArgv[] = {
    "isPrime.exe",  // First argument is the name of the program
    number,         // The actual first argument
    NULL,           // Array must be `NULL` terminated
};

execvp("isPrime.exe", primeArgv);
```

Comment: Okay this worked! However what I don't understand is that we're suppose to be defining and running the Morph function inside of prime.c which is the isPrime.exe so it's basically morphing itself?

Comment: @user3373360 Do you understand the concept of recursion? This is just the same, but with programs instead of with functions.

Comment: Yes I understand that it's a form of recursion however when I run the program it still only seems to run once. After I create the executable I run './isPrime.exe 1535068679' it only checks the number, says it's not a prime number and then the program exits. Should it not continuously run and repeat the above step?

Comment: @user3373360 The `atoi` functions returns an `int` which on just about all platforms are 32 bits, even on 64-bit systems. So the number you pass is simply to big and `atoi` will not be able to handle it. Use [`strtoll` (or `strtol`)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) instead.

Comment: Okay, how would I use strtoll in this situation? 'Morph(strtoll(what parameters?));'

Comment: the contents of primeArgv[] has to be all pointers so a direct number 'number' will not produce the correct results.